# Transforming a BoundaryMeshRegion

Tags: graphics, mesh

I want to transform a `BoundaryMeshRegion` but cannot find a way that conforms with the syntax. As given below, it doesn't work if I generate the `BoundaryMeshRegion` first and then perform a `GeometricTransformation` or vice versa. I have also tried `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` in this fashion, which also doesn't work.

```
reg1 = GeometricTransformation[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1/4]], 
   ShearingTransform[ArcTan[1/2], {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]];

reg2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   GeometricTransformation[
   Cone[{{0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1/4], 
   ShearingTransform[ArcTan[1/2], {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) instead of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation):

```
TransformedRegion[
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{0,0,1/2}, {0,0,0}}, 1/4]],
    ShearingTransform[ArcTan[1/2], {1,0,0}, {0,0,1}]
]
```

[image]